# How to change value of StaticResource in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have static resource in my app.xaml where i want to change the value, but it gives the exception below:

```
<Application.Resources>
      <sys:Int32 x:Key="Test">80</sys:Int32>
</Application.Resources>
```

In code behind to change the value

```
App.Current.Resources["Test"] = 120;
```

Exception

```
The method or operation is not implemented
```

How to change the value of the field?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change that value at runtime. But you can do something like this:

```
App.Current.Resources.Remove("Test");
App.Current.Resources.Add("Test", 120);
```

Comment: Thanks, Though it works, but when i close the app and re-run it doesn't provide me the saved value, It gives me the very old value.

Comment: Static resources are not made to persist values. You should search into things like IsolatedStorageSettings or the different database solutions for Windows Phone like SQL CE or Sterling.

Comment: Correct, you set that value in your App.xaml, which is the runtime value. If you change the value during runtime, the value is not remembered after you end your session.